# Navigation bar disappears when pushing to the next viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently the home page of my application hides the navigation bar; however, whenever I attempt to push that controller over to the next viewController it also hides that navigation bar too. I currently have this is the view controller WITHOUT a navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: mapView animated:YES];
```

Whenever this pushes to the next one it does not have one anymore. The next viewController's navigation bar is in the `viewWillAppear` method, so it should show up. Any ideas?

**ANSWER:**

If you hide your navigation bar in a ViewController and wish to show it in the next one then use the following code:

```
someVC *VC = [[someVC alloc] init];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: VC animated:YES];
```

@LithuT.V and @Tendulkar Thank you!

Comment: in home page how you hide the navigation bar?What is the size of VC and which device you are testing?

Comment: I hid it with the code above. Both ViewController views are the same size.

Comment: Whenever I unhide the navigation bar and then pushViewController the navigation bar shows up.

Comment: The code does only push. To set it hidden you must set `NavigationBarHidden:NO`

Comment: in your mapView controller's viewWillAppear unhide navigation bar . and in it's viewWillDisAppear again hide navigation bar . i hope this will fix it.

Comment: @LithuT.V Thank you! your answer was correct! I posted the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write this code in the ViewDidload method of mapView

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO` works too and it doesn't need to access navigationBar or it's properties directly.

Answer (score 2):

I spent two hours trying to show my navigation bar on a view controller pushed from a different storyboard.

Note that only one navigation controller is needed in main storyboard, then for your view controller where the navigation bar disappears hide it and show it again by the following code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have weird problem, navigation bar hides only for first time after installation, I am pushing an viewcontroller from an sdk's storyboard. I hope your solution works from me.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are hiding your navbar from storyboard, try the below code:

```
//Show navigationBar for a particular VC

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];  
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;` in your next viewControllers `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

This will show the navigation bar for the viewController